# Unable to calculate the ETA and directions using iOS mapkit for chinese poi's

Tags: ios, mapkit, apple-maps

Currently, my application has a feature of displaying the ETA and directions(mapkit framework provided by apple) between two locations/poi's. but when we test this feature by passing some Chinese POI's, i always get the error saying directions not available for this location. I had even verified the map features support page from apple and china is listed under directions features.
So how can i identify as what causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i had figured out the issue.
The problem, was with the accessibility of the chinese data outside china. The mapkit api's worked pretty well when tested inside china with Chinese Network.